# Specifying Title URL in List View Webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, xslt-list-view-web-part

I want to set the Title Url something like

```
/sites/somesite/SitePages/MySearchPage#Default={\"o\":[{\"d\":1,\"p\":\"AverageRating\"}]}
```

where 'AverageRating' is one of my columns using which I am trying to run my query to the search page. While setting the above Url the webpart prompts as the Url is invalid. Also, I have tried setting 'listUrlDir' property of context in my javascript but that also didn't work out.

Somebody guide me with the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way out. Just in case if my solution can help, this is what I did.
I made the title url hidden and then using jquery defined a tag for the required url. And for the strings part in the url, I tried this function

```
encodeURIComponent(variable)
```

which worked fine for me. :)